# Book set in the future about virtual worlds

Tags: story-identification, virtual-worlds

I am looking for this book. It was a rather lengthy book about a bunch of people in virtual worlds, and set in the future. The stuff I remember had one character playing a fantasy virtual reality world, and getting killed by skeletons because he sees a glitch like a bright portal. He comments on how he wound up dead by creatures he's killed a thousand times before, how he has to start all over again and that he has to complain to the people who made the game. This book also has clothes that change color among other future stuff.

Comment: Approximately when did you read this? Was it a paperback? Normal novel-length or so, around 200 pages? Were the color-changing clothes inside the game, or outside of it?

Comment: Sounds like the beginning to The City and the Stars or Against the fall of Night

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50145/story-with-vr-worlds-for-the-wealthy

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like a scene from Tad Williams' Otherland.

> ...a rather lengthy book...

Book 1 is around 800 pages.

> ...a bunch of people in virtual worlds...

"...widespread availability of full-immersion virtual reality installations, which allow people from all walks of life to access an online world..."*

> ...set in the future.

"The story is set on Earth near the end of the 21st century, probably between 2082 and 2089..."*

> ...character playing a fantasy virtual reality world, and getting
>   killed by skeletons because he sees a glitch like a bright portal. He
>   comments on how he wound up dead by creatures he's killed a thousand
>   times before, how he has to start all over again and that he has to
>   complain to the people who made the game.

"In North America, Orlando Gardiner and his friend Sam Fredericks, famous contestants in the Middle Country, a Medieval fantasy gameworld, go on an apparently routine quest, where Orlando finds his own image of the golden city. While he is distracted by the image, his gaming character is killed, and he becomes obsessed with finding out what the city is and why it was shown to him. "*

- from [this Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otherland)

Comment: Yeah, the scene where he's talking about Orlando getting killed by skeletons is from the first book, City of Golden Shadow.

Comment: Anyone reading this interested in the book would be much better off reading "Memory, Sorrow, and Thorn" by the same author and far superior imho. Otherworld seemed a bit gimmicky.

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer.